# "Unused argument" error in function (if...else) when putting external vector as argument

Tags: r, function, unused-functions

I'm trying to set up a function that takes values from a single vector, performs some initial checks and finally does calculations, in case checks found suitable input. Here's a simplified version of the issue I'm facing:

I need a vector, consisting of two placeholders for values

```
vec <- c(a,b)
```

Then, I set up the function tt:

```
tt<-function(vec)
    if(a > b){
        return("ERROR")
    }else{message("ok")}
```

and enter two test values:

```
tt(1,2)
```

...this, however, produces "Error in tt(1, 2) : unused argument (2)".
I've tried defining the vector vec(a,b) in other ways, such as:

```
a<-vec[1]
b<-vec[2]

tt<-function(vec)
    if(a > b){
        return("ERROR")
    }else{message("ok")}
```

or

```
tt<-function(vec)
    if(a > b){
        a<-vec[1]
        b<-vec[2]
        return("ERROR")
    }else{message("ok")}
```

The whole if/else works just fine when I enter the placeholders directly into the function, as in:

```
tt<-function(a, b)
    if(a > b){
       return("ERROR")
    }else{message("ok")}

tt(1,2)
```

So I'm assuming the problem must be caused by my inability to put the vector into the function correctly. I'm very grateful for any input on how to phrase this properly for R to understand.

Comment: I think you should include your function between brackets `{}`. You should open one braket after your arguments and then close it after the else block closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider your function definition. First, you need an extra set of curly brackets.

```
tt<-function(vec){
    if(a > b){
        return("ERROR")
    }else{message("ok")}}
```

Second, in English, your function `tt` accepts a single argument `vec`.

Now let's consider your function call:

```
tt(1,2)
```

In English, you want to evaluate `tt` with the arguments `1` and `2`. However, your function only accepts one argument. Therefore you get the error: "Error in tt(1, 2) : unused argument (2)", because the second argument, `2` is unused.

How can we fix this? First, we can define `a` and `b` based on `vec`:

```
tt<-function(vec){
    a <- vec[1]
    b <- vec[2]
    if(a > b){
        return("ERROR")
    }else{message("ok")}}
```

Now we can call `tt` with one argument, a vector that contains two elements:

```
tt(c(1,2))
#ok
tt(c(2,1))
#[1] "ERROR"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The extra curly brackets did solve the issue, for the more complex, "real" function too! I'm very excited :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to call : `tt(c(1,2))` and not `tt(1,2)`